# displaying googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, mapping

Iam developing an application that show google maps,but the map could not shown {only squares} . i think the problem is comming from this error shown on log cat {04-23 12:33:29.094: E/MapActivity(307): Couldn't get connection factory client} . I want to know whats the problem come from? is it need more permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: are you connected to net.? did you entered correct map keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:--

Open command prompt and use it.

That is the exact path for cmd prompt--

```
keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\XYZ\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Total path for cmd prompt to get the MD5 fingureprint for the GoogleMap API Key*******

```
D:\eclipse\jre\bin>keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\XYZ\.android\debug.keystore"
```

MD5 fingurePrint will look like this--

```
3E:F4:D6:E6:93:4D:BB:B8:62:3A:D6:0F:E0:FC:4C:65
```

When u get the fingurePrint number afterthat to get the API Key use this link---

```
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html
```

Then u will get API key of your system and can get the Map easily by using this API key in your xml file....

Answer (score 0):

You need the map api key. Follow these steps exacty. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Specially take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Answer (score 0):

If there is a **mismatch** between *keystore used to create Google Api key* (using MD5 fingerprint ,and to get MD5 fingerprint keystore required) and *keystore used to sign application*, then this type of problem can occur.

For example, If you are debuging your application then it will use debug.keystore , so api key used in application must be generated using debug.keystore.